# como obtener diferencia de dias con php y mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Buen dia tengo una consulta sencilla que me complico lo que necesito hacer es una alerta de guion el cual una vez trasncurridos dos dias despues de la fecha de registro (en mi base de datos se llama

$ fecha_regis de tipo date) saldra un alert

```
 if ($ fecha_regis > 2) {echo 'alert ("No puedes seguir editando"); window.location.href = "permisos.php.php"; ';}
```

mi duda es como puedo generar la consulta para consultar el día de hoy y la fecha_regis de mi tabla para que salgan contados los días y aplique el si que sean dos días pasados ​​de la fecha de registro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes crear un objeto `DateTime` con el valor de `$fecha_regis` y calcular la cantidad de días transcurridos entre esa fecha y la fecha actual con el método [`diff()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php) de la clase `DateTime`.

Por ejemplo:

```
$fecha_regis="2020-06-20"; #Fecha imaginaria aquí para prueba
$regisDate = new DateTime($fecha_regis);
$todayDate = new DateTime();
$mDays=$regisDate->diff($todayDate)->format("%R%a");
if ($mDays > 2) {
    echo 'alert ("No puedes seguir editando"); window.location.href = "permisos.php.php"';    
}
```

Comment: tengo un campo de fecha_regis en mysql ese lo quiero tomar ya probe la solucion y no me a funcionado

Comment: $fecha_regis = $usuario['fecha_regis'];
$regisDate = new DateTime($fecha_regis);
$todayDate = new DateTime();
$mDays=$regisDate->diff($todayDate)->format("%R%a");
if ($mDays < 2) {
    echo 'alert ("No puedes seguir editando"); window.location.href = "permisos.php.php"';    
}

Comment: ¿Podrías imprimir `$fecha_regis` y decirme qué muestra para ver qué formato tiene? ¿Seguro que es del tipo `Date` en la BD? @SLOKERMENDOZA

Comment: no me la imprime pero la tengo como date

Comment: if(isset($fecha_regis)) echo $fecha_peticion;

Comment: es de tipo date

Comment: @SLOKERMENDOZA si n o te la imprime significa que la fecha no está llegando y por tanto así es imposible que el código funcione. Debes revisar por qué la fecha no llega o llega en blanco. Haz un `var_dump($fecha_regis );` a ver qué muestra.

Comment: ya quedo gracias mi estimado disculpa las molestias

Comment: No es molestia @SLOKERMENDOZA, me alegro de que te haya servido. Saludos.